# Documentation on the differences of drop shadow modes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, drop-shadow

Forgive the noob question but I have been searching (unsuccessfully) for documentation of what the different modes in the drop shadow wizard actually do?  There are more than a dozen options for drop shadow "mode"... can someone please point me to documentation in order to understand the differences between them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called **Blending modes** and for full description of it you should look straight by the source of app, like on this page:

[Blending modes in Adobe Illustrator](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transparency-blending-modes.html)

Comment: This is what I was looking for... but you provided the Ps link.  This is Ai: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transparency-blending-modes.html